# Mysql Event schedule daily start at specific time and stop specific time

Tags: mysql, innodb

I wanted to schedule the event to do some task (insert is dummy). The process should run daily at morning 8:00 AM and should be run every 5 min. till 8:00 PM. As per my script it ran for one day but next day it did not trigger.

Looking for the work around on this.
Event is :-

```
Drop event if exists test; 
CREATE EVENT test
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 28800 SECOND )
    ENDS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 72000 SECOND )
  DO
     insert into temp (name) values (concat('event_name ', sysdate()));
```

Note:- **Global event scheduler is ON**

Comment: Conditionally execute the insert.

Comment: `.. DO BEGIN IF CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN '08:00' AND '20:00' THEN {action code} END IF; END`

Comment: And don't drop and recreate the Event every day.